# Jetty warning - same java class on multiple locations

Tags: java-8, jetty, shibboleth, jetty-9

I'am running Shibboleth IDP with Jetty 9.4.12 servlet container and somehow Jetty warns me with these:

```
07:55:31.629 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.Json scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/Json.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/Json.class
07:55:31.634 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonArray scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonArray.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonArray.class
07:55:31.634 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonArrayBuilder.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonArrayBuilder.class
07:55:31.634 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonBuilderFactory scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonBuilderFactory.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonBuilderFactory.class
07:55:31.634 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonException scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonException.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonException.class
07:55:31.635 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonNumber scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonNumber.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonNumber.class
07:55:31.635 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonObject scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonObject.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonObject.class
07:55:31.635 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.class
07:55:31.635 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonReader scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonReader.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonReader.class
07:55:31.637 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonReaderFactory scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonReaderFactory.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonReaderFactory.class
07:55:31.637 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonString scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonString.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonString.class
07:55:31.637 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonStructure scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonStructure.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonStructure.class
07:55:31.637 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonValue$1 scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonValue$1.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonValue$1.class
07:55:31.638 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonValue$2 scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonValue$2.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonValue$2.class
07:55:31.638 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonValue$3 scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonValue$3.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonValue$3.class
07:55:31.639 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonValue$ValueType scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonValue$ValueType.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonValue$ValueType.class
07:55:31.640 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonValue scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonValue.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonValue.class
07:55:31.640 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonWriter scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonWriter.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonWriter.class
07:55:31.640 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.JsonWriterFactory scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonWriterFactory.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonWriterFactory.class
07:55:31.641 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.spi.JsonProvider scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/spi/JsonProvider.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/spi/JsonProvider.class
07:55:31.641 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.stream.JsonGenerationException scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonGenerationException.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonGenerationException.class
07:55:31.641 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonGenerator.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonGenerator.class
07:55:31.641 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.stream.JsonGeneratorFactory scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonGeneratorFactory.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonGeneratorFactory.class
07:55:31.642 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.stream.JsonLocation scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonLocation.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonLocation.class
07:55:31.642 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.stream.JsonParser$Event scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonParser$Event.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonParser$Event.class
07:55:31.642 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.stream.JsonParser scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.class
07:55:31.642 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.stream.JsonParserFactory scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonParserFactory.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonParserFactory.class
07:55:31.643 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] - javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonParsingException.class, jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/stream/JsonParsingException.class
```

It seems those classes are used in javax.json-1.0.4.jar and javax.json-api-1.0.jar. Any idea why Jetty want's to warn these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broken down.

- 07:55:31.635 - WARN [org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser:569] -

  - javax.json.JsonNumber scanned from multiple locations:
  - jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.0.4.jar!/javax/json/JsonNumber.class,
  - jar:file:///opt/ps/jetty/jetty-base/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-idp.war-_idp-any-8184658660181054677.dir/webinf/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.0.jar!/javax/json/JsonNumber.class

This is a warning produced during the bytecode scanning for annotations of a webapp startup.

The existence of multiple versions of the same class is a source of errors and bad behaviors.

In your case, you have 2 versions of the same class, version `1.0` and `1.0.4` as seen by the JAR filenames.

Since a ClassLoader has no JAR file load order expectations and requirements, it's possible that executing the same WAR at different times will result in different behaviors.

Jetty cannot make the determination on how severe the issue of duplicate classes is, that's up to you to decide.  Jetty can only produce this warning for a common behavioral problem in webapps.

To address this, you'd need to correct the produced WAR file to only include 1 copy of each class.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Good clarification! I think it's safe to ignore those warnings then. Shibboleth consortium seems to use those .jar files in their libraries by default, so there must be some kind of explanation to that.